# java on windows terminal doesn't output files

Tags: java, windows, terminal

I wrote Java code in FileWriter, and when I run it on the Windows Terminal, it's supposed to output a file to the folder it's running on, but it doesn't.

Sometimes it works miraculously, but most of the time it doesn't.
When I run the same code on my school's Linux machine, there are no issues and the files are outputted just fine, which eliminates the possibility of a faulty code.

**What I don't know is what's the cause of the problem**, it can't be java because javac is working properly, right? If so can you help me fix this problem?

This is the code I use just for reference:

```
File file1 = new File("simulation.txt");
FileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter(file1);
try {
    writer1.write(mips.simulationText);
    writer1.close();
}
```

Comment: O.K. I posted an answer suitable for new user, got negative vote - delete it... I suppose It should be the comment. My suggestion was to write following statement before writing to the file to see where is the file actually stored:`System.out.println(file1.getAbsolutePath());`... Good luck.

Comment: i saw your comment and i executed it, it gives me the same directory as the .java file, but sadly there is no file being created in that directory :(

Comment: that's it, i found the issue, it seems that the files are being created in a different desktop, i found it though, thank you very much appreciate it a lot

Comment: Glad to help you. Go ahead...